# Output of mysql function is not as expected

Tags: mysql, function, input, output

I have total 3 entry in Employee Table with below table schema.
Employee(ID,FirstName,LastName,Salary)
Table Entry as follow.

```
ID FirstName LastName Salary
1  ABC       abc      10000
2  PQR       pqr      2000
3  XYZ       xyz      19000
```

I have create a function getFullName as below.

```
Delimiter $$
Create Function getNamae(d_id INT) Returns varchar(200) deterministic
Begin 
   Declare full_name varchar(200) Default "";
   select concat(FirstName,LastName) INTO full_name from Employee where ID=d_id;
   Return full_name;
END $$
```

I have called this function as below

```
Select getNamae(2) as full_name 
from Employee
```

But I getting Output PQRpqr 3 times.

Shouldn't the output be PQRpqr only once?

Please can any one could tell me why this happen. I am beginner and not able to understand.

Comment: Of course. The function is called for each source row, and each time it returns the same output. You need `Select getNamae(id) as full_name from Employee WHERE id = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the name of employee 2, you don't need to select from the table. Just use

```
SELECT getNamae(2) as full_name;
```

When you use `from Employee` it calls the function for every row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Query should be like this

```
Select getNamae(2) as full_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different approach. In MySQL you can create virtual columns in your table, the value of a virtual column is **calculated**, much like a formula in Microsoft Excel.

Check the examples at the very bottom of [this page in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) - it is exactly your use case, concatenating first and last name.

Comment: While this may be a good idea, it doesn't really have much to do with why he's getting 3 results when he only wanted 1.

Comment: @Barmar, you are completely right, and your answer is relevant, but since in the question it is said that "beginner", I thought it would be helpful to offer a built-in solution for what he is trying to re-invent.

Comment: I usually put such recommendations in a comment.

Comment: @Peter 
Thank you telling this approach. I am not aware about virtual column in MySQL. I learn a new thing from you.